# Tkinter class issue

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter, parameters

My aim is to create a default class with the properties of a window that can be inherited by other windows.

```
from tkinter import *
class window():
        def __init__(self, Width, Height, Bg):
            self.Width = Width
            self.Height = Height
            self.Bg = Bg

            object = Tk()
            frame = Frame(width=Width, height=Height, bg=Bg)
            frame.pack()


class child_login(window(768, 576, "ORANGE")):

    def __init__():


        Label(frame, text = "Username").grid(row=0)
        Label(frame, text = "Password").grid(row=1)
        e1=Entry(frame)
        e1.insert(10, "name")
        e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        e2=Entry(frame, show = "*")
        e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        Button(frame, text = "Quit", command = master.quit).grid(row=3, column=0)
        Button(frame, text = "print", command = display_entry).grid(row=3, column=1)
        mainloop()


child_login()
```

For the child_login class I wanted a frame that inherited window() properties yet had the labels and buttons defined beneath. Unfortunately I get two windows created and the error

> tkinter.TclError: bad screen distance "child_login"

Answer (score 1):

You can not initiate classes when inheriting them. You inherit classes first and *then* initiate them separately.

So instead of this:

```
class child_login(window(768, 576, "ORANGE")):
```

Do this:

```
class child_login(window):

    def __init__(self):
        window.__init__(self, 768, 576, "ORANGE")
```